# JX browser 6.21 fails to initialize

Tags: jxbrowser

We are trying to upgrade JX browser from 6.5.1 to 6.21.

We are having several problems with this.

One is occasional problems initializing the jx browser.

Here some errors from the log:

```
ERROR [2018-08-13 19:05:02,581] (null:-1) - 07:05:02 SCHWERWIEGEND: [0813/190502.567:FATAL:window_impl.cc(196)] Check failed: ::IsWindow(parent).
ERROR [2018-08-13 19:05:03,158] (null:-1) - 07:05:03 SCHWERWIEGEND: Failed to execute task
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Channel stream was closed before response has been received.
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ipc.SocketChannel.post(SourceFile:221)
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.Browser.b(SourceFile:624)
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.Browser.getURL(SourceFile:2046)
    at ov$e.onFinishLoadingFrame(Unknown Source)
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.aa.run(SourceFile:3400)
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.r.run(SourceFile:79)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

ERROR [2018-08-13 19:06:58,011] (null:-1) - com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ipc.IPCException: Failed to get Browser browserChannel 4
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.Browser.a(SourceFile:485)
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.Browser.<init>(SourceFile:402)
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.Browser.<init>(SourceFile:348)
    at ... calling code ...
```

What could be the problem here?

Comment: It may be that you have to change default folder for Chromium . I had the same problems , deleted the previous folder which i had said to (`Chromium`) using properties and made it to create a different one called (`Chromium2`) . `System.setProperty("jxbrowser.chromium.dir",  "Chromium2");`

Comment: Many juicy stuff has changed between versions . It even broke when updating from 6.19 to 6.21 .

Comment: works on ubuntu 16 but not 18

Comment: I ended up with @GOXR3PLUS 's idea but also included the version-number of JX in the path, thus running older and newer version in parallel or alternatingly won't create any trouble.

Comment: I wonder why JxBrowser has not open source licenses anymore .... very bad :(